# Share one database between two ruby on rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have an existing sqlite database from an existing ror application, and would like to set up a new rails app simply so my users can only view records in the db. How can I set up a scaffold linked to my existing db. The db name is as default "development.sqlite3" and has one table called "library". this table is for showing images in a slideshow.(only contains paperclip type value for image and the automatically generated id.)

I heard I have to configure the config/database.yml, and then create a model without migration, and next? how to edit new model map to the correct table automatically.

---UPDATE1:

I have tried to create a model with the same name with the original table without migration
and edit the model like followng:

```
class Library < ActiveRecord::Base


 self.table_name = "library"

end
```

In this way I can access all columns now...
but the library table also have a paperclip type value(for image "house"), house_file_name; house_content_type; house_file_size;house_updated_at; can I show the original images from this database based these columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the model in the new app uses the same naming as the original app, it will use the same table by default.  If you want to specify a table for the model to use that doesn't follow rails conventions, you can call `table_name=` in your model:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "library"
end
```

Comment: Thank you,I have tried that like this                                    class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.table_name = "library"
   self.primary_key = "id"
end      but I can only access the id column in that table, there is  paperclip type(for image) in this table,  could I also access such columns like house_file_name,house_content_type,...?

Comment: @user2096263: Then you should be fine using a similar model in your new app.

Comment: I can access the whole table now. but as the original table stores the information for images, can I show the image in my new app based on this database?